# Documentation tab like stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request

Stackoverflow developers created a [very useful page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) that leads to tutorials in many disciplines, each with various topics.

We could significantly benefit from this feature

Disciplines here could include:
Motors, LEDs, Embedded C, Circuit Analysis, etc...

However these disciplines may need better segregation seeing that in stackoverflow case it's mostly **languages** and **libraries**, whereas here we could have more than 2 categories, like

1. **Circuit Design**

   - LED Driver
   - Op Amp
   - Motor

     - Intro to types of motors
   - Voltage Regulator
   - Rectifier
   - Relays
2. **Microcontrollers programming**

   - PIC

     - Oscillator
     - GPIO
     - PWM
   - Atmega
   - Serial Communication
3. **Filtering**
4. **PCB**

Comment: I only recently learned about "documentation" myself, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around what exactly it is, and how it compares/contrasts with the regular tag system and with the "community wiki" system. If there are too many ways to do similar things, it becomes harmful rather than helpful -- information becomes fragmented rather than consolidated. But I agree, it does sound like something EE could use. (I'm also thinking that it's something that [Retrocomputing](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) could use as well.)

Comment: @DaveTweed: I know it for a while and dislike it in the context of SE for specifically the reason you mentioned: it fragments information and causes duplicated work. The Q&A format is something unique to SE and doesn't fit the style a lot of people want/expect. Here it seems that another style is piggybacked on the QA style and imho it looks horribly wrong. It may be nice to collect information in that way, but that should be an entirely different community or community type. Also the fact that many people only recently learned about it, and much more don't know it yet makes me worry even more

Comment: I have a [question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291077/222992) seeking additional information that is stimulating some discussion.